# Is there a way to lock the linux scheduler on a particular pthread?

Tags: linux, pthreads, real-time, scheduler, vxworks

On *VxWorks* there is a function called `taskLock` which prevent a task from being rescheduled.

On *Linux* we've a good lock's fan as the mutex and semaphore but the *VxWorks*' `taskLock` function permit a task to disable interruption without interacting with the other ones.

At this point i know that i can use `pthread_setcancel_state ( PTHREAD_CANCEL_DISABLE, NULL )` but the function i'm looking for is doing a little more. More than just a interruption disable, the  `taskLock` function completely disable task switching. It give, to the calling function, the entire ressources the calling process/parent have.

The way *Linux* manage the pthread is quite different. **What would be the best way to simulate a `taskLock` call on *Linux*, with the pthreads ?**

Here's a quite description gave by the datasheet :

> This routine disables task context switching. The task that calls this routine will be the only task that is allowed to execute, unless the task explicitly gives up the CPU by making itself no longer ready. Typically this call is paired with taskUnlock( ); together they surround a critical section of code. These preemption locks are implemented with a counting variable that allows nested preemption locks. Preemption will not be unlocked until taskUnlock( ) has been called as many times as taskLock( ).

thank you for having a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a directly analogue in userspace (kernel tasks can disable preemption), but this effect is typically achieved by using a realtime scheduling policy (`SCHED_FIFO` or `SCHED_RR`) with a higher scheduling priority than the other tasks.